# why *args doesn't work with string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand Python *args and **kwargs operates. Let's consider a function which takes 4 arguments. We can pass list x as argument to function using *x

```
def foo(a,b,c,d):
    print a,b,c,d

x=[1,2,3,4]

foo(x)
#TypeError: foo() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

foo(*x)
#1 2 3 4 # works fine

print "%d %d %d %d" %(*x)
#SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if I got it correct, in case foo() *x unpacks values...then why error in case of `print "%d %d %d %d" %(*x)` ??

Note- I am not interested in how to print a list in one line but just curious why `print "%d %d %d %d" %(*x)` not works.

Comment: you could also just make x a tuple: `print "%d %d %d %d" % tuple(x)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*x` unpacks the contents of `x` into arguments, as opposed to a tuple; and a tuple is what `%` should be passed.

```
print "%d %d %d %d" % tuple(x)
```

Comment: You mean ``" ".join(map(str, x))`` :)

Comment: Or `' '.join(str(i) for i in x)`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [the new way of formatting strings in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings). In fact, it is much more elegant and does exactly what you expect it to do:

```
"{} {} {} {}".format(*x)
```